# passing parameter

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-3

how do i pass the value of selected types over? I want to pass it from here:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedType, Model.Types, new { @onchange = "getSpecificFields(value in here)",})
```

the problem is, after i make the first initial drop down selection, everything loads properly. But if i go to change my selection the page doesn't update to the new selection. How would i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.SelectedType, 
    Model.Types, 
    new { 
        onchange = "getSpecificFields(this.value)"
    }
)
```

and then:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getSpecificFields(value) {
        $.get('@Url.Action("CreateSpecific", "Employee")', { type: value },
            function(data) {
                $("#specificFields").replaceWith(data);
            }
        );
    }
</script>
```

or using completely unobtrusive javascript:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.SelectedType, 
    Model.Types, 
    new { 
        id = "myddl",
        data_url = Url.Action("CreateSpecific", "Employee")
    }
)
```

and then in a completely separate javascript file:

```
$(function() {
    $('#myddl').change(function() {
        var data = { type: $(this).val() };
        var url = $(this).data('url');
        $.get(url, data, function(result) {
                $("#specificFields").replaceWith(result);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: @BlueMonster, see my second and better alternative using unobtrusive javascript which completely avoids you mixing server side code with javascript and allows you to place your script in a separate javascript file.

Comment: how would i get it to update when a new selection is made from the dropdown list? thought i could just re-load window avoce the $.get, but that doesn't work.

Comment: What do you want to update. I don't understand your question at all.

Comment: i have 2 different types of employees.. on the first round, when one is selected the form displays everything properly. but if i try to select the other right after, i have to re-load the page entirely and start fresh for it to update the page properly.

Comment: Why do you have to reload the page? I thought you wanted to use AJAX. I still don't understand.

Comment: i've updated the Q with photos and a proper description so you can see what's happening, and hopefully understand what i mean - sorry. bad at explaining things at times..